# Controlling phone Apps using Laptop's keyboard and mouse

Tags: 8.1, windows-10, keyboard, lumia-640-xl, continuum

I know there are some apps that can do the opposite. But I want an app that can allow me to use PC mouse and keyboard to control my phone apps. Actually, I want to play Modern Combat 5: Blackout phone version using my external mouse and keyboard. The reason I can't play on my Windows 10 laptop is because of my low system configuration. And I am currently not in a position of buying a new hardware.

Please suggest me any app or method that can help me?

Laptop: Windows 10

Phone: Windows Phone 8.1 on Microsoft Lumia 640 XL

Answer (score 1):

Project my screen app from Microsoft for windows phone allows this. It's for Win8/10 only and has some limitations. Install it on desktop, plug in phone, enable screen sharing on phone.

Comment: Yeah I know about it. But it does not provide keyboard input.

Answer (score 0):

With WP version 8.10.15116.125 (WP 8.1.2) support for hardware keyboards was added. So I think you can use bluetooth keyboard with your phone.